# Run RCP application without installing Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I am new to RCP appication. Is it possible to run RCP application without installing eclipse. I mean can we run the rcp application like ther java application(like Swing application)?

Answer (score 6):

An Eclipse RCP application usually contains everything from Eclipse it needs, so yes, you don't need to install Eclipse just to run an Eclipse RCP application.

Comment: I'd also mention, that with an RCP application, the created product has a native executable to be started with, so for Windows, it has a `.exe` file (initially eclipse.exe of course, but you can rename that), so the users can open it as if it was a completely native application, way more conveniently, than for example with a Swing .jar. Opening JAR files seem to confuse even semi-experienced users.

Comment: In my point of view the other answer "Eclipse Product export wizard" put me into the right direction how to achieve a clean deployment even my question was the same: how to run .product (I am new to Java/RCP)

Comment: Well, the question was "if" it is possible, not "how" to do it. E.g. asking "if" might be enough for an evaluation. Giving an answer to "how" will, of course, help you further.

Answer (score 0):

Use your .product file and on the Overview Tab, click on "Eclipse Product export wizard" and follow the instructions. The wizard will generate all your app needs to run and an .exe file. You'll can use this file to launch your app !

Comment: The exported product does indeed include an executable, but this is just an launcher that will invoke Java to run the "real" application...

Comment: The original question was "Is it possible to run RCP application without installing eclipse ?". I give a way to do that by exporting the RCP app. So what's the problem ?

Comment: Reading your answer, one will assume that the complete application is contained in the executable, which is not the case...

Comment: But it is not the point... I'll update my answer anyway to avoid misunderstandings.

Comment: Thanks for putting me into the right direction. Your answer really helped me!